# store result of query into a varible - SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Have a question

.[image: my_table]

I have a table "my_table" as shown in the image.
I have created a variable called "variable_1" and I am running a query within that:

```
DECLARE @variable_1 nvarchar(4000) = 'SELECT Header FROM my_table WHERE rule = ''rule_1'''
```

when I execute this, `exec(@variable_1)`

I get result:

Header

---

- op1
- op3

I want to store the result of **variable_1** into a new variable "Variable_2" .
Can I do something like this?

```
DECLARE @variable_2 nvarchar(4000) = exec(variable_1)
```

Eventually I want to store the result of variable_1 (which will be op1,op3) into variable_2 and print a  command like "SELECT op1, op3 from..."

SELECT (result from variable_1)....

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @variable_2
```

So when I print @sql, I get result:
***SELECT op1, op3***

Thank You!

Comment: i am not able to figure out what exactly you require

Comment: @Sreenu131  - I want to store the result of variable_1 (which will be op1,op3) into variable_2 and print a command like "SELECT op1, op3 from..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Table')IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Table
CREATE TABLE #Table (Header varchar(10),[Order] INT,Rules   varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #Table
SELECT 'op1',1,'rule_1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'op2',2,'rule_2' UNION ALL
SELECT 'op3',3,'rule-3' 

SELECT * FROM #Table

DECLARE @variable_1 NVARCHAR(4000) = 'SELECT STUFF((SELECT '', '' + Header FROM #Table  WHERE Rules IN( ''rule_1'',''rule_2'') FOR XML PATH ('''')),1,1,'''')'


DECLARE @Temp TABLE (variable_2 nvarchar(4000))
INSERT INTO @Temp
EXEC (@variable_1)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

SET @sql = (SELECT 'SELECT ' + variable_2 +' From' FROM @Temp)
SELECT @sql AS ExpectedResult
--PRINT @sql
```

Result

```
ExpectedResult
--------------
SELECT  op1, op2
```